# Different field used as foreign key, cannot insert

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony5

I have 2 table with relations. Here is my schema.

### product_model

```
CREATE TABLE `product_model` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model_number` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `model_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_model_number` (`model_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

### product_color

```
CREATE TABLE `product_color` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model_number_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `color_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `product_product_color` (`model_number_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_model_color` FOREIGN KEY (`model_number_id`) REFERENCES `product_model` (`model_number`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Now when I try to insert product color, I am getting following error message

`An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

I have used following lines on code to insert.

```
$modelFound = $em->getRepository(ProductModel::class)->findOneBy(['modelNumber' => $modelNumber);


$insert = new ProductColor();
$insert->setModelNumber($modelFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are passing the full object instead of the model ID during your insert.

Your code should be :

```
$modelFound = $em->getRepository(ProductModel::class)->findOneBy(['modelNumber' => $modelNumber);

$insert = new ProductColor();
$insert->setModelNumber($modelFound->getModelNumber());
```

But, if you are using the full ORM (not only the DBAL), can you post your mapping files. You should have a setModel method and not a setModelNumber method.